# Blackberry BBM Service not working with webworks SDK

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I don't know i've tried hell lota tutorials and samples but when i do testing on my DAB it does not work, while the same code of sample works on the same device, i'm feed up what to do? Can you suggest me good tutorial teaching how to that from scratch or can you provide me with the simplest sample? Please i really need help ;_;

Comment: Did you add permissions and settings?

Comment: yes :(
<feature id="blackberry.app" />
 <feature id="blackberry.app.event"/>
 <feature id="blackberry.system.event" />
 <feature id="blackberry.bbm.platform" />
 <feature id="blackberry.invoke" />
 <feature id="blackberry.invoke.card" />
 <feature id="blackberry.system" />
 <feature id="blackberry.ui.toast" />

 <!-- Required permissions. -->
 <rim:permissions>
  <rim:permit>bbm_connect</rim:permit>
 </rim:permissions>

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help more, I'm on cascades. If samples work, try wo go line by line to see what it has differently. Unless you give some source, we can't really help you

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me exactly what you're trying to do?

We have a sample app which should outline absolutely everything needed in order to integrate BBM into your WebWorks app.

It looks like the feature includes and access permissions are fine in your config.xml from what I can see here.

Check out the sample app: https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/bbm

Comment: sample is working fine but when i copy that code it does not work, i'm trying https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.bbm.platform.html this sample to code, that sample is too complicated for me to edit and use, so i'm using that simple one, but it's not working i don't know what's the problem :(